# Unicode characters are not properly rendered in transpiled JS

Tags: javascript, html, unicode

I have a simple transliteration application which works well in simple JavaScript (in a file named `cctest.js`).

```
function parse() {
    return '\u0d85';
}
```

The test HTML I have used is as follows.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="cctest.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="dist/cctest.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        console.log(parse());
        console.log(CCTest.parse());
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I have decided to refactor this into follows so that I leverage object-oriented aspects better (`src/cctest.js`).

```
export default class CCTest {
    parse() {
        return '\u0d85';
    }
}
```

`src/index.js`

```
import CCTest from "./ccctest";

(function(window){
    window.CCTest = new CCTest();
})(window)
```

I have configured this to be transpiled using webpack and babel, which works. But when I open the test page, I have the following results in the console.

[image]

As you can see, the plain JS renders the Unicode without any issues, while the JS transpiled with Webpack and Babel gives a gibberish. I looked into everywhere I would possibly put my hands on, but I am having a hard time figuring out whats going on. Can someone please point out what am I doing wrong here? (I have deliberately avoided the content of the config files to keep this short. Please comment, if you need to take a look into those. I am happy to post those as well.)

Comment: It's a [mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake) case.`අ` in UTF-8 is byte sequence `0xE0`,`0xB6`,`0x85` which appears as `à¶�` if interpreted as _latin1_ characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I dug a little deeper, I figured that it was a problem with the minification of the file. During the minification, the unicode literal `'\u0d85'` is being replaced with its actual unicode representation, resulting in the minified version having `...return 'අ'...`, which results in the Mojibake `0xE0`, `0xB6` and `0x85` (thanks [JosefZ](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3439404/josefz) for his hint on Mojibake.)

Managed to fix this with the use of a 3rd party minifier [uglifyjs-webpack-plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/uglifyjs-webpack-plugin). The configuration in `webpack.config.js` for this would be something along the lines of

```
const UglifyJsPlugin = require('uglifyjs-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = (env = {
  minify: false
}) => {
  return {
    ...,
    optimization: {
      minimize: env.minify && env.minify === 'true',
      minimizer: [new UglifyJsPlugin({
        uglifyOptions: {
          output: {
            // true for `ascii_only`
            ascii_only: true
          },
        },
      })],
    },
    ...
  }
};
```

The key here is to configure the minifier to use only ASCII characters by using the config option `ascii_only: true`. That resolved the problem for me.